# FATAL: Cannot generate COM file : invalid initial entry point adress

Tags: assembly, tasm

While linking this asembly file  using `Tlink /tdc` command I got the `FATAL: Cannot generate COM file : invalid initial entry point adress.` error message. I don't know how repair this BUG. What should I change in my code to make this program able to start.

```
.MODEL HUGE
org    100h

;.386
.code  
Dane            SEGMENT
DL_TABLICA      EQU     10
Tablica         DB      01h, 02h, 00h, 10h, 12h, 33h
                DB      15h, 09h, 11h, 08h, 0Ah, 00h
Najmniejsza     DB      ?
Dane ends
Kod SEGMENT 
ASSUME  CS:Kod, DS:Dane
                ;jmp     Poczatek

Start:


                mov     ax, 4C00h
                int     21h
Kod ENDS

End     ;Endprog
Start
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The `.MODEL` for .COM programs is "tiny".
2. .COM programs have only one segment. So you shouldn't use any `SEGMENT`, `ENDS` or `ASSUME` directive in it. A single `.CODE` serves the purpose. Therefore, at the beginning should be code, not data.
3. A .COM program starts always at the beginning. To give it a label is just for satisfying TLINK.
4. A .COM program starts with `DS`=`CS`. You don't need to initialize `DS` (`mov ax, @data` `mov ds, ax`).

A simple Hello World program:

```
MODEL tiny
.CODE
.386                        ; Just to show at what position it has to be
ORG 0100h

Start:

    mov ah, 09h             ; http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2562.htm
    mov dx, OFFSET hello
    int 21h

    mov ax, 4C00h           ; http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2974.htm
    int 21h

hello:  db "Hello World", '$'

End Start
```